# Android Wear Error ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null} when the smartwatch sends data

Tags: android, google-play-services, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm sending a signal from the mobile app to the smartwatch and upon its reception, the smartwatch generates a signal and sends it to the phone app. The app works fine as long as the phone is the one sending the data but whenever the app tries to send something, the following error is generated:

> Android Wear Error ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null}

Following is my Wearable's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.Gavras:GIFView:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
}
```

Following is my Mobile app's dependencies file:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir:
            'libs')



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:2.0.2.1'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    compile 'com.victor.ringbutton:lib:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.shem8:material-login:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.timqi.sectorprogressview:library:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
  //  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0'
   // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

    compile 'io.github.yuweiguocn:SquareLoading:1.3.0'
    compile 'nl.psdcompany:duo-navigation-drawer:2.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
    compile('com.github.thekhaeng:pushdown-anim-click:1.0.7') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.github.zjywill:OverwatchProgress:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.vlad1m1r990:Lemniscate:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.2'

}
```

I tried the other answers of trying to update the google-play-services by clicking them in the wearable's settings but nothing happens.
I also tried re-syncing the apps from the mobile but to no avail.

Comment: What version of Google Play Services is actually on both of your devices?